# Input type hidden for kendoNumericTextbox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

It is possible to make this textbox hidden while Im using kendoNumericTextbox on it? [Working Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IkEcoyAS)

```js
$("#sum_of_itemGrid").kendoNumericTextBox({
  spinners: false,
  format: "{0:n2}",
  decimals: 2,
  restrictDecimals: true
}); 

$("#sum_of_subRecipeGrid").kendoNumericTextBox({
  spinners: false,
  format: "{0:n2}",
  decimals: 2,
  restrictDecimals: true
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="sum_of_itemGrid" class="k-textbox" />
<input type="hidden" id="sum_of_subRecipeGrid" class="k-textbox" />
```

I have tried

```
document.getElementById("sum_of_itemGrid").style.display='block';
document.getElementById("sum_of_itemGrid").style.visibility='visible';
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it, need to use wrapper

```
$("#sum_of_itemGrid").data("kendoNumericTextBox").wrapper.hide();
$("#sum_of_subRecipeGrid").data("kendoNumericTextBox").wrapper.hide();
```